# How to hide specific wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, filter, posts

I have a simple question... I would like to filter some of the posts, where the post name (slug) is a date value. I want to hide posts where the post name value is lower the todays date...

Is it possible?

Comment: This question is flawed, and shows virtually no effort at researching a solution.  Closing is duplicate.  (Flawed because you should filter post date by post date, not by post slug).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter out event posts older than current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042032/filter-out-event-posts-older-than-current-date)